# How do I add a task bar to my second monitor in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have a laptop and an external monitor with it. My external monitor is set as primary monitor. So my task bar only appear in external monitor. But I want the task bar to appear on both monitors.

I found [this](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/130) github issue but it is closed now. So I don't know if this feature is added or not. Or if there are any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added in [version 2.6](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2015/02/recent-cinnamon-development/) of Cinnamon. You can add another panel on your second monitor by right clicking your current panel, clicking `Modify panel...` and then `Add panel`.

You'll see a message asking you to select where to put the new panel, which you can add where you want it on your second monitor. You can mirror the panel configuration on the other monitor by copying and pasting from your main monitor. Once you do that, any application you have open on the second monitor will have its window on the second monitor's panel.

If you're unsure which version of Cinnamon you have installed, this terminal command will tell you:

```
cinnamon --version
```

If your version is lower than 2.6, you'll have to update to a newer version of Mint.

Alternatively if you're using Mint 17.1, though I wouldn't recommend this as it might cause problems, you can [update Cinnamon](https://mintguide.org/system/443-how-to-update-cinnamon-to-the-latest-version.html) to 2.6 without updating your version of Mint by using these steps:

1. Open `Software Sources`
2. Check the box for `Unstable packages (romeo)`
3. Click `Update the cache`
4. Open `Update Manager`
5. Click `Refresh` and then `Install Updates`

Comment: well, the problem is even though I add another panel running task is not shown in both panel. For example, if I open firefox browser, it only show in one panel but I want to show it in both panel. I know this is possible in ubuntu. But I don't know how to do it in linux mint